# Left join + count based on column comparison

Tags: sql

I'm not sure why this won't work: see the [sqlfiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c697b2).

I have two tables

Table 1:

```
Unsub|Email|UnsubValue
Y    | a   | 100
Y    | b   | 200
N    | c   | NULL
N    | d   | NULL
```

Table 2:

```
Email|UnsubValue
a    |100
a    |200
b    |100
b    |150
c    |300
```

I want to count the number of times an email occurs in Table 2 *and* the unsubValue in table 2 is less than the unsubValue in Table 1. So the desired output is this:

```
Email|UnsubCount
a    |1
b    |2
c    |0
d    |0
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: ah the code I used isn't showing. It was giving me errors anyways. Want to give it a shot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty direct application of `LEFT JOIN` and `GROUP BY`:

```
select t1.email, count(t2.email)
from t1 left join
     t2
     on t1.email = t2.email and t2.UnsubValue < t1.UnsubValue
group by t1.email;
```